# What does Betapropin do?

Tags: die2nite

I'm on day 3 of the Die2nite beta, and I noticed that a "Betapropin tablet 5mg" has appeared in my inventory as a professional tool.  The mouse-over description in the "Use an object from my rucksack" section states "this small tablet has a somewhat surprising effect..."

What does this tablet do?  I'm guessing since it's a drug, it will refill my AP.  What is the "surprising effect"?  Does it being a professional tool make it special in any way?

Comment: The being a professional tool means you can't drop it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a one-time item given out by the developers to beta testers. Using it sets your AP to 30/6. It doesn't count as a drug for the purposes of the "Clean" status (i.e. you're still clean after using it).

It's marked a "Professional tool" and therefore can't be dropped. If a person carrying one does manage to drop it somehow (i.e. by dying) it can't be picked up again by anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

You get 30 AP as opposed to the usual 6. Use it wisely.

Apparently there's a side-effect from using it; I haven't seen what that is yet.

Comment: The side-effect can be becoming addicted, drugged, terrified, or any combination of the three.

Comment: So does this mean I will end up with 30/6 AP, or is my AP still capped by my maximum?  Does the object persist?  Will I get a new one if I die and start in a new town?

Comment: You'll be raised to 30/6, but you'll lose the AP on the days reset, and if you're not at 0, you'll waste a few AP.

Comment: I've never seen or heard of any side effects from using the drug. Has anyone actually seen this happen?